# How to get count from pivot table laravel?

Tags: laravel, eloquent, count

I have two tables,

```
  User          cities            user_cities

id name        id   name       user_id   city_id
1   aaa        1   cityA         2         1
2   bbb        2   cityB         2         3
3   ccc        3   cityC         1         2
                                 3         3
                                 3         2
```

Now i am `filtering the user by cities`. I am having the `city_id = 2`. So that i have to get the count of users belongs to the city_id 2.
How can i get that using laravel eloquent

Answer (score 0):

If you have set correctly the relationship between them, you can do something like that:

```
City::where('id', '=', 2)->withCount('users')->get();
```

It will place a {relation}_count column on your resulting model, and thus you can call it like a property: `$city->users_count`

Edit: For further information, you can check the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#counting-related-models).

Answer (score 0):

As you describe in your answer you have the third table `user_cities`.

If you have table `user_cities` then count user like

```
DB::table('user_cities')->where('city_id', '2')->count();
```

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to do this, check https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries

But a simple way of doing it could be:

```
UserCity::whereCityId(2)->count();
```

Or:

```
UserCity::where('city_id',2)->count();
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this query :

```
$count = City::where('id', 2)->whereHas('users')->count();
```